# Which area in Act 1 can I gain Nephalem Valor the fastest?

Tags: diablo-iii

### This question is now obselete due to patch 2.0.1 as NV has been removed from the game.

---

I am trying to quickly build up 5 stacks of [Nephalem Valor](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Nephalem_Valor) before tackling [the Ponies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-whimsyshire-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii).  Which area in act 1 gives the highest chances of spawning multiple uniques and champions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nephalem Valor no longer exists in the game. You cannot farm it at all, no matter where you go.

Answer (score 8):

I would say the Cemetery of the Forsaken.

With a chance for a [unique](http://www.diablowiki.com/Lucious_the_Depraved) to spawn, plus three very small dungeons, two of which are one level only with exit teleporters, you should be able to find 5 stacks in a very short amount of time.

Comment: Look at my answer to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71718/inferno-act-1-gold-farming-skeleton-king-vs-butcher/71724#71724, I mention those areas and how to get stacks very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the Cemetery of the Forsaken and the Warrior's Rest and Crypt of the Ancients (the two caves/crypts you need to enter before you can enter the drowned temple).

The latter two only if you haven't got 5 stacks from the cemetery alone yet.

Answer (score 1):

Another very good area would be Festering woods. The area is quite small and usualy has 3 elite groups by itself. There also are 2 very short dungeons with 1 elite group in each.

A lot faster than cemetery of the forsaken since the area is much, much smaller. However, the trash deals more dmg, so you have to have a bit better gear.

Comment: Agree that Festering Woods is also a good choice (potentially, 2 elite mobs + last stand + dungeons could give 5 stacks there itself) - more damage shouldn't be a problem if he is doing Inferno ponies.