# I've been farming Inferno Act 1, but slowly. What is the most efficient Act 1 run?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inferno Act 1 Gold Farming, Skeleton King vs. Butcher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71718/inferno-act-1-gold-farming-skeleton-king-vs-butcher)

The title says it all. I've been farming the Butcher, but I know that there's gotta be a more efficient farming route in Act 1. Anybody have any good spots?

Comment: that post was from before patch 1.03. I'm looking for stuff after 1.03 because I know it changed up Nehpalem Valor.

Comment: It is fine to ask for updates to an old question, we don't need to create a new question each time that the answer changes.

Comment: And my answer is from a day or two ago, and I can assure you it's post 1.0.3 :P

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Hard to find since it only had 3 upvotes :/

Comment: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6036886898#4 has a very nice order & explanation

Comment: Re. the 'original', if this is going to be marked as a dup shouldn't that one remove the references to specific bosses and Gold from the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 1.03 hit, I’ve been doing this particular elite run.  Since elite packs now guarantee a rare when you have full valor, wasting five stacks of Nephalem Valor and repeating a Butcher run is simply not as efficient as pre-1.03.   Act 1 is especially great, because there are relatively small areas with concentrated and guaranteed numbers of elites.  My runs normally culminate in the killing of the Warden and Butcher.  The places I go are:

- The Watchtower (1-5 elites)
- The Festering Woods (2-4 elites) Leoric’s
- Manor (and courtyard) (1-2 elites)
- Cemetery of the Forsaken (and the Defiled Crypts) (3-4 elites, sidequest)
- Halls of Agony (lvl 2, 3) (2-6 elites)
- Cursed Hold (1-5 elites, Warden)
- Highlands Passage
- Chamber of Suffering (Butcher)

Remember that added movespeed can add a lot to the speed of your runs.

Video with some additional info about efficiency of runs:

(sorry I'm not sure how to embed on this site)

[Source](http://www.diablo3strategyguide.com/inferno-act-1-runs#elite).